# UIAlertView in cell

Tags: ios

i have a UITableView and i want a specific cell to be an alert view when i touch it.
how could i do that please? 
how to load an alertView into the cells ?

```
@synthesize courses, courseKeys, courses_web, courseKeys_web;


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (section == 0) {
        return [courses count];
    } else {
        return [courses_web count];
    }
}


- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (section == 0) {
        return @"iOS Courses";
    } else {
        return @"Web Courses";
    }
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] 
                initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }

    NSString *currentCourseName;

    // Which section are we in?
    if ([indexPath section] == 0) {
        currentCourseName = [courseKeys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    } else {
        currentCourseName = [courseKeys_web objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    [[cell textLabel] setText:currentCourseName];


    // Now, get the author name
    NSString *currentAuthorName;
    if ([indexPath section] == 0) {
        currentAuthorName = [courses objectForKey:[courseKeys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    } else {
        currentAuthorName = [courses_web objectForKey:[courseKeys_web objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    }
    [[cell detailTextLabel] setText:currentAuthorName];

    // Retrieve an image
    NSString *imagefile = [[NSBundle mainBundle]  pathForResource:@"cellimage" ofType:@"png"];
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:imagefile];
    // Add the image to the table cell
    [[cell imageView]setImage:image];

    // accessory type
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;


    return cell;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    NSString *myfile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                        pathForResource:@"courses" ofType:@"plist"];
    courses = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:myfile];
    courseKeys = [courses allKeys];


    myfile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                        pathForResource:@"courses_web" ofType:@"plist"];
    courses_web = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:myfile];
    courseKeys_web = [courses_web allKeys];
```

Comment: I'd suggest you format your code properly. It's hard to read as it's currently standing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Selection of tableCell,Add UIAlertView in didSelectRowAtIndexPath delegate method.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   if(indexPath.row == //specific row)
{
// show alert view
}
}
```